# Acumatica: Automation Steps not functioning on a Extended Screen?

Tags: acumatica

I have Extended the SOOrder screen to a new custom screen, i have added an approval automation to add a custom action menu to the custom screen.
[image: Reservation Screen]

This are the steps the i have done:

## Step 1: I created an automation step for Reservation Screen

- Screen ID: Reservation(RE31018)
- Step ID: SC Hold - Pending Approval
- Description: SC Hold - Pending Approval
  Condition: 
  [image: Conditions for Reservation Step]

## Step 2: I went to the Automation Definition to Activate the Automation Step

[image: Automation Definitions for Reservation]
After i have done all of this steps, the automation step didnt work.

I tried to uncheck all the SOOrder IN automation step for the SOOrder page, and it seems that the automation steps that it uses sales order steps. 
is there any other way around to activate that steps without disabling the existing steps?

Comment: I am guessing you are using a graph extension? You might need to inherit the sales order graph vs a graph extension so it can have its own automation steps and truly be its own graph for a new page.

Comment: Hello @Brendan, i have already inherited the SOOrder graph but some of its functionality of it wouldn't work by default. i tried to inherit the AR,PO,AP and its working fine, its seems that there is a problem regarding the SO? have you encountered the same problem?

Comment: I have not tried it on sales order. What doesn't work?

Comment: first is the screen wont initialize it doesn't load the stored data, when you click the add button the "<NEW>" doesn't appear and the buttons Action,Release doesn't work.